# bootstrap - aligning columns within a div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am current uni student working on a project.
I am trying to create a div with multiple image on the left and text and a button on the right.
The problem I am having is that the elements are not lining up. I am using bootstrap classes for this.

The images below are of my current output and what I would like to achieve.[image: current output]

[image: expected output]

and here is the code:

```
<style>
   #points{display:block;}
</style>
<div class="row" style="border:black solid 2px;">
  <div class="col-8">
     <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/450x250" />
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/210x150" /></div>
      <div class="col-3"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/210x150" /> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="col-4" >
       <div class="property-wrap">
            <div class="text">
              <h3><a href="#">Name </a></h3> 
              <ul class="property_list mt-3 mb-0">
                <li><span class="flaticon-bed"></span>3</li>
                <li><span class="flaticon-bathtub"></span>2</li>
                <li><span class="flaticon-blueprint"></span>1,878 sqft</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
           <div class="text">
               <p>This here is some sample text. This is going to be a mini paragraph. This here is some sample text. This is going to be a mini paragraph. This here is some sample text. This is going to be a mini paragraph. </p>
               <ul > 
                <li id="points">test</li>
                <li id="points">test</li>
                <liid="points">test</li>
                <li id="points" >test</li>
               </ul>
               <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#!">View More →</a>
           </div>
          </div>
        
        </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to expand the width of the text div so it is next to the images. ( I assume this would shrink the whole div as well - I would like the size of the images).

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT:
after trying the code in the answer
my page now looks like this
[image]

it is  looking better but i would like to condense it - see the blue line i added.

here is the updated code

```
<div class="row" style="border: red 2px solid; margin: 50px;padding: 10px">
    <div class="col-8">
        <div class="row" style="border: yellow 2px solid; padding: 2px">
            <div class="col-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="instagram.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6" style="border: yellow 2px solid; padding: 2px"> <img class="img-responsive" src="product.jpg" /></div>
            <div class="col-6" style="border: yellow 2px solid; padding: 2px"> <img class="img-responsive" src="product.jpg" /> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4" style="border: gray 2px solid; padding: 2px">
        <div class="property-wrap">
            <div class="text">
                <h3><a href="#">Name </a></h3>
                <ul class="property_list mt-3 mb-0">
                    <li><span class="flaticon-bed"></span>3</li>
                    <li><span class="flaticon-bathtub"></span>2</li>
                    <li><span class="flaticon-blueprint"></span>1,878 sqft</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <p>This here is some sample text. This is going to be a mini paragraph. This here is some sample text.
                    This is going to be a mini paragraph. This here is some sample text. This is going to be a mini
                    paragraph. </p>
                <ul>
                    <li id="points">test</li>
                    <li id="points">test</li>
                    <liid="points">test</li>
                        <li id="points">test</li>
                </ul>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#!">View More →</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This can be easily achieved with table, but you want to use bootstrap column based structre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this hope it works for you

```css
 img{max-width: 100%; width: 100%;  border:yellow 2px solid}
 .outer{ border:red 2px solid}
 .right_text{border: gray 2px solid; padding: 15px}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container outer">
  <div class="row">
  
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 my-3">
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/3b/24/c7/3b24c709566eaab86b97a99b9c084c4c.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/3b/24/c7/3b24c709566eaab86b97a99b9c084c4c.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/3b/24/c7/3b24c709566eaab86b97a99b9c084c4c.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
    
    <div class="col-sm-6 my-3">
    <div class="right_text">
      <h3>TEXT COLUMN</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris... Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris... Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris... Ut enim ad minim veniam,.</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment if have any query

Comment: looking a lot better, how could i shrink the gap inbetween the two smaller images? would like them a bit closer together but with the overall size still inline with the image above

Comment: Add CSS on image `width: 100%`  Code updated please check.... And right side height depends on the content

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
    #points {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<div class="row" style="border: red 2px solid; margin: 50px;padding: 10px">
    <div class="col-8">
        <div class="row" style="border: yellow 2px solid; padding: 2px">
            <div class="col-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/450x250" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6" style="border: yellow 2px solid; padding: 2px"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/210x150" /></div>
            <div class="col-6" style="border: yellow 2px solid; padding: 2px"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/210x150" /> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4" style="border: gray 2px solid; padding: 2px">
        <div class="property-wrap">
            <div class="text">
                <h3><a href="#">Name </a></h3>
                <ul class="property_list mt-3 mb-0">
                    <li><span class="flaticon-bed"></span>3</li>
                    <li><span class="flaticon-bathtub"></span>2</li>
                    <li><span class="flaticon-blueprint"></span>1,878 sqft</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <p>This here is some sample text. This is going to be a mini paragraph. This here is some sample text.
                    This is going to be a mini paragraph. This here is some sample text. This is going to be a mini
                    paragraph. </p>
                <ul>
                    <li id="points">test</li>
                    <li id="points">test</li>
                    <liid="points">test</li>
                        <li id="points">test</li>
                </ul>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#!">View More →</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for this, I was more looking for yellow box to be the same size as the images, I am trying to scale it down and make it look smaller so it doesn't take up so much room on the page.  and then i would like to expand the text on the right so its not as long

Comment: please see my updated question- i would like the text to be wider so it isnt as long as well